# How can we run camera as background view in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I would like to test around a bit with augmented reality.How to get the picture that comes from the camera as background for my view? For what I want to do, I don't need to access the picture, I just need it as background.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the preview-buffer from the camera from the page. We need this to capture a QR-Code without taking pictures with the camera.

Initialize the camera object

```
_phoneCamera = new PhotoCamera();
_phoneCamera.Initialized += CamInitialized;
```

In the Initialized - Event. Just create the buffer

```
private void CamInitialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _previewBuffer = new WriteableBitmap((int)_phoneCamera.PreviewResolution.Width, (int) _phoneCamera.PreviewResolution.Height);
}
```

Ant then you can take everytime a snapshot of the current view:

```
//grab a camera snapshot
_phoneCamera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(_previewBuffer.Pixels);
_previewBuffer.Invalidate();
```

And then you can do what you want with this WriteableBitmap (show as background, or whatever).

Or (if I misunderstood your question) here a link with the info, how to add the camera-view to your page (this is also needed for the above solution): [How to create a base camera app for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: i need camera on Start menu as background. Like Once User open the app and press main menu icon of device, then there should be camera view on the main page too.

Comment: What do you mean with the "main menu icon of device"? The link in my post above shows, how to place a camera-view within a canvas on a single page. If this is not what you are looking for, please describe exactly what you want to achieve.